# Шрифт перестал поддерживать кириллицу после переноса сайта

Tags: wordpress, шрифты

После переноса сайта на WP с одного хостинга на другой используемые шрифты перестали поддерживать кириллицу.
На старом сайте хостинге все на сайте отлично работает.
После переноса нужные шрифты подтягиваются только, если используется латиница.
Сам файл стилей, очевидно, тоже работает нормально.

Ссылка на старый адрес: http://devs.hostoasis.net/agroflora/www/

Новый: http://agroflora.ru/

Comment: А Вы пробовали developer tools включить? Там выдает ошибку `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` со ссылкой на файлы шрифтов.

Comment: Да, эти ошибки я видел. Но суть в том, что это совсем не те шрифты, которые не работают (еще просто не удалил ненужные пути к ненужным шрифтам, которые уже удалил). Не работатют с кириллицей именно те, которые успешно загрузились

Comment: Фишка именно в том, что с латиницей все нужные шрифты прекрасно работают на всех страницах

Comment: Ну вообще-то Ваш CSS указывает на шрифт, для кторого ttf файл возвращает 404. Вы уверены, что все загрузилось? Шрифты в WordPress - часть темы, так что там никаких проблем с доступом быть не должно... если файлы есть - они читаются...

Comment: Я понимаю о чем Вы говорите, но ошибку 404 выдает для шрифта, который не используется нигде. Все остальные подключились, но не работают с кириллицей.

Comment: может  отличие в форматах шрифтов? на одном ttf на другом woff. Начертание-то одинаковое, размер и жирность отличаются только

Comment: Отличие между стилями ваших сайтов в том, что на "проблемном" у вас не загружается последний импортируемый в каждом правиле шрифт (тот, который в svg-формате). Есть вероятность, что браузер, умеющий работать со всеми форматами шрифтов, пытается рендерить тот, ссылка на который следует в импорте последней, а она - битая (например, тут есть: http://devs.hostoasis.net/agroflora/www/wp-content/themes/cookbook-child/fonts/SourceSansPro-LightIt-webfont.svg а тут нет: http://agroflora.ru/wp-content/themes/cookbook-child/fonts/sourcesanspro-light-webfont.svg). Попробуйте посмотреть в этом направлении.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, рассмотрел этот вариант, но исправление не помогло. Помогла только перезаливка файлов шрифтов напрямую но новый сервер